# Equation as excel axis title

Tags: excel

I'd like to use as axis title an equation in excel 2016, there is no official 
way it seems. Would anyone happen to know a good solution?

I tried to paste my equation as a picture from clip board, but it looks horrible.

Comment: Perhaps write the equation in TeX choosing a font as close as possible to what Excel shows.

Comment: Seems to be a question about Excel and is therefore off-topic here, sorry.  Nevertheless: Welcome to TeX.SE!